# Spreedsheet IF statement being weird

Tags: worksheet-function, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

So I got two equations:

```
=SUM(C1:INDIRECT("C"&H5))+(H1*H5)
```

And:

```
=SUM(C1:INDIRECT("C"&H3))+(H1*H5)+(K1*(H5-H3))
```

Now I want them in a IF statement like this:

```
=IF(A1>$H$3;($C$1:C1)+($H$1*C1)+($K$1*(A1-$H$3));($C$1:C1)+($H$1*A1))
```

It's redone so I can put it in a cell and drag it down to calculate the numbers I want to put in a graph.

But where the individual calculations work as intended the If statement show something else even when i just make it like this:

```
=IF(H5>H3;(C1:INDIRECT("C"&H3))+(H1*H5)+(K1*(H5-H3));(C1:INDIRECT("C"&H5))+(H1*H5))
```

But when kept in separated cells and just referred to they work:

```
=IF(H5>H3;K6;K5)
```

Why this weird behaviour and how do I fix it?

Comment: what application are you using ? Excel ?

Comment: LibreOffice but I haven't noticed much difference between Libre and Excel except the user interface is a bit different.

Comment: i cant say for Libre what is wrong with it, but in an EXCEL format it works fine in an example i just tried. As long as there is a value in H3

Comment: Ok. Will try in excel.

Comment: just remember to swap ; for ,

Comment: Will do. Thank you anyway. Thought I needed to wait for an answer till tomorrow.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. You should report it so it can be fixed: https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/QA/BugReport

Comment: This does not look like a bug to me, nor do I see any unexpected behavior.  However, it's hard to be certain without example data and expected results.  To add these, please edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

The formulas that work are the ones that have `SUM`.  It looks like you forgot to include that in those that don't work.

For example, `(C1:INDIRECT("C"&H3))` from the `IF` statement will result in an array of values, not a single result.  Presumably, you intended to write `SUM(C1:INDIRECT("C"&H3))` instead, as in the first formula.